R base pipe can't be referenced with backticks? could not find function "|>"
I'm trying to build a wrapper around the base pipe |> to do some modification to the left-hand side and then pipe it forward normally. While working on this I found the following peculiarity about the base pipe compared to other operators:
Work as expected:
`+`(1,2)
#> [1] 3

`<-`("foo", 1)
foo
#> [1] 1

library(magrittr)
`%>%`(1, print)
#> [1] 1

Does not work as expected:
`|>`(1, print)
#> Error in `|>`(1, print): could not find function "|>"

This means that, for example, while the following works fine with the magrittr pipe
as.call(c(as.name("%>%"), "foo", substitute(print)))
#> "foo" %>% print

and can be passed to eval():
eval(as.call(c(as.name("%>%"), "foo", substitute(print))))
#> [1] "foo"

It does not work for the base pipe:
eval(as.call(c(as.name("|>"), "foo", substitute(print))))
#> Error in `|>`("foo", print): could not find function "|>"

I've struggled to find documentation on this because I'm not quite sure how to describe this problem, and google often doesn't play nice with queries involving special characters, even in quotations.
Edit: more detail on the context
As a toy example, say we want to make a pipe variant that pipes the name of the object, rather than the object, and without otherwise changing our usage:
library(magrittr)
`%>>%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  # get lhs as a character
  lhs.name <- deparse(substitute(lhs))
  
  # the parent environment
  parent <- parent.frame()
  
  # the environment in which to evaluate pipeline
  env <- new.env(parent = parent)
  
  # magrittr version
  eval(
    as.call(c(as.name("%>%"), lhs.name, substitute(rhs))),
    env, env
  )
}

foo_func <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  print(arg1)
  print(arg2)
  print(arg3)
  arg2 + arg3
}

thing %>>% foo_func(2,4)
#> [1] "thing"
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 4
#> [1] 6

To avoid the magrittr dependency, I was interested in making this work with |> instead of %>%. It appears we can substitute in
eval(
    str2lang(paste0("'", lhs.name, "'", " |> ", deparse(substitute(rhs)))), 
    env, env
  ) 

though I have not yet tested it thoroughly.

The base pipe is not a function, like the other operators are. Instead, it is implemented as a syntax transformation, see ?pipeOp and the quote(mtcars |> subset(cyl == 4) |> nrow()) example.

@Axeman thanks. Do you have any suggestions for how to use it when coding on the language, then? I can't call quote(|>) on its own, for example, when building a call inside a function where the left-hand side and right-hand side are passed in.

I'm not sure if you can? But since the syntax is transformed by the parser anyway, why build the "foo" |> print() call at all, and not just print("foo")?

The context is hard to fully explain here, but I need to eval() the expression in the parent environment. I guess I can just treat the base pipe as a string and do str2lang(). So eval(as.call(c(as.name("%>%"), "foo", substitute(print)))) from above could be redone as eval(str2lang(paste0("'foo'", "|>", deparse(substitute(print()))))).

The base pipe isn't the only operator that isn't really an operator.  -> and ->> are transformed into <- and <<- by the parser.  The thing about these is that none of them are needed to form R expressions; they are all just "syntactic sugar".

Even with your comment above, I don't understand why @Axeman's suggestion won't do what you want.  Could you edit your question to explain what you are trying to do that requires |>?

@user2554330 Sure. I've done so.

Thanks!  But for better clarity, you might want to show us the full definition of %>>% that you're trying.  The left hand side of a pipe doesn't necessarily have an obvious name, e.g. c(1,2,3) |> mean().

1) If the question is how to implement "%>>%" without dependencies then copy insert_dot source code from the poorman source code at
https://github.com/nathaneastwood/poorman/blob/master/R/pipe.R
and modify the source code of %>% on the same page to be:
"%>>%" <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  rhs_call <- insert_dot(substitute(rhs))
  eval(rhs_call, envir = list(`.` = substitute(lhs)), enclos = parent.frame())
}

# tests

if (exists("xyz")) rm(xyz)

xyz %>>% paste0("*")
## [1] "xyz*"

xyz %>>% paste(., .)
## [1] "xyz xyz"

2) All we are really saving with this new pipe operator is one leg in a pipeline containing substitute.  May it is sufficient not to define a new piping operator at all and just write:
xyz |> substitute() |> paste0("*")
## [1] "xyz*"

xyz |> substitute() |> ( \(x) paste(x, x) )()
## [1] "xyz xyz"

or use quote
xyz |> quote() |> paste0("*")
## [1] "xyz*"

xyz |> quote() |> ( \(x) paste(x, x) )()
## [1] "xyz xyz"

3) If a dependency on magrittr is ok then
library(magrittr)

"%>>%" <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  eval.parent(substitute(lhs %>% substitute %>% rhs))
}

